# Cast function to member-function

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I want cast function to member-function and then call it, but `self` has some adjustment to this `self_3 = self_1 + self_2`

```
struct Foo {};

namespace FooExt {
    Foo* getSelf(Foo *self) {
        return self;
    }
};

template <typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
auto f2mf(R(func)(T*, Args...)) -> R(T::*)(Args...) {
    return (R(T::*&)(Args...)) func;
}

int main() {
    auto getSelf = f2mf(FooExt::getSelf); // getSelf: (Foo* (Foo::*)(Foo* const)) 0x557f0a9ac210 <FooExt::getSelf(Foo*)>, this adjustment 140735536657056

    Foo f{};

    auto self_1 = &f;
    auto self_2 = (((Foo*) nullptr)->*getSelf)();
    auto self_3 = (f.*getSelf)();

    return 0;
}
```

What are the reasons? How to do this properly?

Comment: reasons? for what? Would be interesting to know for what reason you want to do such a cast

Comment: reasons of `this` adjustment https://pasteboard.co/II3RJPr.png 
I just experiment with C++

Comment: What is a `this adjustment`? What is the point of `f2mf`? Do you just want `std::bind`? `(((Foo*) nullptr)->*getSelf)()` is very wrong and undefined behavior,

Comment: please include relevant information in the question, please copy the text, please no links and no images

Comment: why do you want to cast a free function to a member function? There are different things...

Comment: I don't want std::bind

Comment: I know that (((Foo*) nullptr)->*getSelf)() is wrong, but I use it for test

Comment: `I use it for test` - your test is wrong. `I want cast function to member-function and then call it` - then you should know that calling a function pointer using a type that is not compatible with the pointer-to type is undefined behavior. You can cast the function, calling the function with different type is undefined behavior, no matter what. From where does the message `// getSelf:` come from?

Comment: @uneven_mark yes, it was Clion output, but `self` is equal to `this` + `this adjustment` inside getSelf function, and I don't understand why

Comment: @KamilCuk it was Clion output in debug mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasoning below was wrong, because 1. member function pointers are not function pointers and 2. you are not actually casting to a member function pointer type, but to a member function pointer reference type.

The undefined behavior here happens already when you initialize the return value of `f2mf` from the reference obtained by the cast. It accesses the referenced pointer with the wrong type, causing an aliasing violation and undefined behavior.

---

The result of explicitly converting a function pointer to another function pointer type is unspecified except that converting back to the original type yields the original pointer value.

Calling the function through a pointer to function type not equal to the original function type causes undefined behavior.

Therefore your compiler can do whatever it wants with the pointer values in your code.

Additionally calling a member function on a null pointer value also causes undefined behavior and also allows the compiler to do whatever it wants.